# how to find HADOOP_HOME path on Linux?

Tags: linux, hadoop

I am trying to run the below java code on a hadoop server.

```
javac -classpath ${HADOOP_HOME}/hadoop-${HADOOP_VERSION}-core.jar -d wordcount_classes WordCount.java
```

but I am not able to locate `{HADOOP_HOME}`. I tried with `hadoop -classpath` but it is giving output as below:

```
/etc/hadoop/conf:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/*:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//*:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/./:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/*:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/.//*:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//*:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/./:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/*:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/.//*
```

Anyone has any idea about this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Navigate to the path where hadoop is installed. locate `${HADOOP_HOME}/etc/hadoop`, e.g.

```
/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/etc/hadoop
```

When you type the ls for this folder you should see all these files.

```
capacity-scheduler.xml      httpfs-site.xml
configuration.xsl           log4j.properties
container-executor.cfg      mapred-env.cmd
core-site.xml               mapred-env.sh
core-site.xml~              mapred-queues.xml.template
hadoop-env.cmd              mapred-site.xml
hadoop-env.sh               mapred-site.xml~
hadoop-env.sh~              mapred-site.xml.template
hadoop-metrics2.properties  slaves
hadoop-metrics.properties   ssl-client.xml.example
hadoop-policy.xml           ssl-server.xml.example
hdfs-site.xml               yarn-env.cmd
hdfs-site.xml~              yarn-env.sh
httpfs-env.sh               yarn-site.xml
httpfs-log4j.properties     yarn-site.xml~
httpfs-signature.secret
```

Core configuration settings are available in hadoop-env.sh.

You can see classpath settings in this file and I copied some sample here for your reference.

```
# The java implementation to use.
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_67

# The jsvc implementation to use. Jsvc is required to run secure datanodes.
#export JSVC_HOME=${JSVC_HOME}

export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=${HADOOP_CONF_DIR}

# Extra Java CLASSPATH elements.  Automatically insert capacity-scheduler.
for f in $HADOOP_HOME/contrib/capacity-scheduler/*.jar; do
    export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=${HADOOP_CLASSPATH+$HADOOP_CLASSPATH:}$f
done
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Contributor [Abdulaziz Alshehri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7227305/abdulaziz-alshehri) notes that with Google Cloud Cluster, the file was in `/usr/lib/hadoop/etc/hadoop`.

Answer (score 4):

hadoop-core jar file is in ${HADOOP_HOME}/share/hadoop/common directory, not in ${HADOOP_HOME} directory.

You can set the environment variable in your .bashrc file.

```
vim ~/.bashrc
```

Then add the following line to the end of .bashrc file.

```
export HADOOP_HOME=/your/hadoop/installation/directory
```

Just replace the path with your hadoop installation path.

Comment: As i am working on the server where hadoop is already installed, so i am not able to locate `${HADOOP_HOME}/hadoop-${HADOOP_VERSION}-core.jar` file

Comment: What's the result of
"echo ${HADOOP_HOME}"? You may need to ask server administrator about the installation directory.

Comment: It is same as HADOOP_HOME, means path is not set. But i got that command running by replacing `${HADOOP_HOME}/hadoop-${HADOOP_VERSION}-core.jar` with the output of `hadoop -classpath` Thanks Chong.

Comment: Some server admins like to put Hadoop in /opt/, you can check there and good luck! :)

Comment: @ChongTang, Could u just explain what is the importance of mentioning java location in .bashrc and hadoop-env.sh. What would happen in the background when hadoop cluster is started. Just wanted to understand how java path is inter related with hadoop deamons